# Simple highslide gallery doesn't display correctly

Tags: highslide

I'm trying to duplicate the look of this simple gallery:

http://www.highslide.com/examples/gallery-white.html

on this page:

http://dreamweavers-quilts.com/studio/products/inchiesee-inchiedo-viewer-tool-and-ruler-set/

Only the first caption is displayed with the picture. The second and third captions are not showing when the pictures are enlarged. The html is exactly the same in my page as it is in the example page, so I'm not sure what's gone wrong.

If I need to provide more details, let me know and I'll do my best. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem about one row the simplest way:

```
<ul class="highslide-gallery">
  <li>
     <a href="your_url1"><img src="your_source1"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="your_url2"><img src="your_source1"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="your_url3"><img src="your_source3"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And css something like this:

```
ul.highslider li
{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Or just add to your css file:

```
.highlslide-gallery a
{float:left;}
```

Comment: Thank you for that BuDen. I did figure out that I could do that with an unordered list if I couldn't get it to work any other way, but I was also able to work out that part of the problem by taking out some extra line breaks that WordPress puts into the post automatically. Sorry I didn't catch that before posting my question. :-)

Comment: Remove <p> which wrap your <a> tag. Just tested it and it works.
You have to organize html structure like in example. 
<a>your_image_here</a>
<div class="highslide-caption">My Caption</div>

Comment: Hmmm...so WordPress automatically inserts paragraph tags where I don't want them. I enabled an addon that prevents it from doing that and the problem with the captions is solved. Thank you for your help BuDen!